# smartctl to find how old is the hard drive

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, hard-drive

I just got a new server from a server provider and he placed in some old 1.5TB HDD. They do support smartctl.

Is there a way I can findout how old these drives are?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to know the HDD's manufacture date (e.g. for warranty issues) the only universal way to get that is to open the case and have a look at the HDD label.

Another possible way is to use `hdparm -i /dev/sdx` or `smartctl -a /dev/sdx` to get the model and serial number and check with the manufacturer's warranty web page. Some manufacturers will provide a manufacture date for each serial number.

`smartctl -a /dev/sdx` will occasionally have a `Power_On_Hours` or other similar attribute which can be an indicator of how long a drive has been in use. Other attributes may also serve this way.

#### EDIT:

For example Seagate provides the warranty expiration date, which can be used to estimate the manufacture date if you know the length of the warranty period. The length of the warranty period usually depends on the model and you should be able to find it by searching the web.

Comment: Wow that was awesome.

Comment: Does this mean 

9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8

It has been on for only 8 hours?

Comment: Yes... one of my disks which I have had for two years and has been on for most of that time is in the 17,000-hour range now.

Comment: Awesome. I was scared that they added in a really old drive but now that it has been used only for 8 hours. I feel much much better

Comment: Well, you could always check the model and serial number with the manufacturer web site to make sure...

Comment: Note "hdparm was not designed to be used with SCSI or SATA drives"  (https://hyperois.com/members/index.php/knowledgebase/30/-Drive-errors-in-the-system-log-files-ordevorsda-HDIOGETIDENTITY-failed-Invalid-argument.html)  so you may get `HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument`

Comment: `sudo apt install -y smartmontools` in case anyone is wondering